# Error in converting datatype from datagrid to datatable

Tags: c#, .net

Beginner in .net:  I am using Datagrid to display an excel sheet and when there are null records, i am getting this error message 
"System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'"

Code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day_of_the_Week", Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours_Total", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your loop, tell us the value of `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text`, and tell us what you want to happen if `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text` is not a DateTime.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse a Date in a format that is not valid, Can you please show what does  ```GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text``` contain?

Comment: Add a check before setting the parameter. What is the datatype of the field filled with the parameter @Day_of_the_week ?

Comment: GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text gets Datetime from an excel sheet. If there is record, the code is perfectly working. In case of null record, i am getting this error message. The data type in database is date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to convert the input field and set with the conversion the parameter. If the conversion fails you shouls use a predefined value for your field or set it to DBNull.Value (if the database can accept null for that field)

```
DateTime minValue = new DateTime(1900,1,1); // Arbitrary for missing values 
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@Day_of_the_Week", SqlDbType.DateTime);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours_Total", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DateTime day;
    if(!DateTime.TryParse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text, out day)
       day = minValue;

    command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
    command.Parameters["@Day_of_the_Week"].Value = day;
    command.Parameters["@Hours_Total"].Value = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Notice also that I don't use AddWithValue. It is a convenient method but has [some serious problems](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to be aware. The Add method allows you to specify exactly the datatype and this datatype should match your database type.
Finally all the parameters could be declared outside the loop and just set the value inside the loop (no need to recreate them at each loop)

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much checks if the content of the cell you are trying to retrieve is a valid datetime, if so it converts otherwise returns the raw info from excel or....

```
DateTime outDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day_of_the_Week", DateTime.TryParse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text, out outDate) ? Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text) : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours_Total",  GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

...return datetime min date if your @Day_of_the_Week param is datetime type:

```
DateTime outDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day_of_the_Week", DateTime.TryParse(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text, out outDate) ? Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text) : DateTime.MinValue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours_Total",  GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am getting this error now.  "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and 'string'"

Comment: The first example will never compile because the two parts of the ternary operator should return the same type. Anyway you can use the out variable in the true part of the operator. Finally do not use AddWithValue (in particular with dates)

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself a helper function, one-liner, that's going to do a small check (say for NULL if you know it can be NULL) and then decide what to you want to give as a default. I usually make one for "normal primitive types types" (meaning CLR's), and one for SQL types. You can also cover nullable variant to be safe.

In you case, since you are doing UI, you may need a 3rd kind - display string defaults. If something that's DateTime is missing the appropriate default might be just empty string or a short word like "not given". That aspect depends very much  on the purpose of a given UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what exactly the type of data you're trying to put within "Day_of_the_Week" - the weekday, a numerical index, the full date?

But, if just a full datetime, you can append it in SQL using STRING syntax like "YYYYMMDD":

```
DateTime outDate;
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true)

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day_of_the_Week",  Datetime.ParseExact(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours_Total",  GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: its a timesheet calculation, day of the week is fulldate. thanks for the response